# Bose gas with $T = 0$ and $\mu < 0$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bosons

Is it possible to have a Bose gas with $T = 0$ and $\mu < 0$ ?

I think that there is a problem, because all the states $k$ are such as

$$\langle n_k \rangle = \dfrac{1}{e^{\beta \{\epsilon_k - \mu\}}-1} = 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the homogeneous ideal Bose gas, where we have:
$$
\langle N\rangle = \sum_{\vec{k}}\frac{1}{\exp{\beta(\epsilon_{\vec{k}}-\mu)-1}}.
$$
The notation $\langle N_{\vec{k}}\rangle$ means the average number of particles in state $|\vec{k}\rangle$, which obviously has to be larger or equal to zero. In the case that $\vec{k} = 0$ we must have 
$$
\left<N_0\right> = \frac{1}{\exp{(-\beta\mu)}-1}\geq0\Rightarrow \mu\leq0
$$
If on the other hand, you keep the average number of particles fixed and start lowering the temperature, the chemical potential must increase (i.e. less negative) to keep the number of particles fixed. At some point you reach $\mu=0$ (for low enough temperature) and the number of particles in the ground state will become macroscopically large.

Comment: Note to possible editors: how do I write a nice average (< ... >) or ket (|..>) in the text?

Comment: You might interested in this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47078

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To sum up : $T = 0 < T_c$ so in this case $\mu$ should be equal to $0$, this is right ?

Comment: @Arnaud, yes I think so.